# Is it possible to create a template in MS Word where the user is being asked for input in input boxes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

We have to write transcripts in our association. While we do have some kind of **MS Word** template, it always tedious to spell out every little repetitive thing, that is common for most transcripts, but different in details.

For example, we *always* note down **the time, the place and the present attendees** in our transcript in a table. Is it possible to create such a template, that when you open it the template asks you in a prompt or input box to state the time and place and it would automatically fill out the data formatted in the correct cells of the table?

Similar thing with the titles of all the sections in the transcript: It would be useful to have some kind of prompt asking for all the different sections and then fill out all the titles of all the sections automatically, formatted in the correct style.

The same would be cool for **MS Excel**.

Is there any way to achieve that? I have seen macros, but they don't seem to be flexible or ask prompts or anything. I'm somewhat confused on how to research that kind of topic.

Comment: Consider using a Cover Page to gather the information. Then use mapped Content Controls. http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart Look into using built-in heading styles and the StyleRef field in your headers/footers. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF *These links go to pages on my website.*

Comment: Content controls and building blocks all the way here. MVP Stephanie Krieger has some great books which cover this (amongst 1000 other things) and some online articles too, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use the ASK or Fill-In field that activates on a new document or you could use a vba UserForm.

A UserForm is more "elegant" but requires that the user allow macros to run. Here are two MVP pages on UserForms.

- [Create and Employ a UserForm](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userForm.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Create a Simple UserForm](http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm) by Graham Mayor

This is intermediate vba work.

The Ask and Fill-In fields do not require macros and are about as old as Word. Insert > QuickParts > Field

Here are the Microsoft Documentation pages on the fields.

- [Ask Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-ask-field-31b8d920-978c-4aba-9dd7-68dd81ffd943)
- [Fill-In Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-fill-in-field-aa773538-91ee-446a-9a58-1cff8db21d59)

The Ask Field is used in conjunction with one or more Cross-Reference (Ref) fields. Having a lot of these fields in a template is annoying.

Here is a link to my [tutorial on Ask and Fill-In fields](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AskField).